# Flutter UI sometimes doesnt change when Firestore updates happen

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I got a Firestore DB and I need some like & dislike functionality. For that I created a class likeAndDislikeButton.dart it just handles both buttons and displays two icons with text beside them (amount of dis-/likes). The Icons should change on click, that works sometimes and sometimes it's just stuck and doesnt do something, even though the database realises the clicks and changes the fields.

That's my class in general:

```
    class LikeAndDislikeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  Game game;
  DatabaseService dataService = DatabaseService();

  LikeAndDislikeButton(
    this.game,
  );
  @override
  _LikeAndDislikeButtonState createState() => _LikeAndDislikeButtonState();
}

class _LikeAndDislikeButtonState extends State<LikeAndDislikeButton> {
  bool _isLiked = false;
  bool _isDisliked = false;
  String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  List<dynamic> userIdsWhichLiked = [];
  List<dynamic> userIdsWhichDisliked = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userIdsWhichLiked = this.widget.game.likes_user_ids;
    userIdsWhichDisliked = this.widget.game.dislikes_user_ids;
    print(userIdsWhichLiked);
    print(userIdsWhichDisliked);
    _isDisliked = userIdsWhichDisliked.contains(currentUserId);
    _isLiked = userIdsWhichLiked.contains(currentUserId);
    return StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: this.widget.dataService.getGameCollection(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  createLikeButton(),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  createLikeText(),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  createDislikeButton(),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  createDislikeText(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Thats how the create___Button() looks:

```
createDislikeButton() {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        width: 50,
        child: Icon(
          this._isDisliked
              ? Icons.thumb_down_alt
              : Icons.thumb_down_alt_outlined,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (_isDisliked) {
            this
                .widget
                .dataService
                .removeFromDisliked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);
          } else {
            if (_isLiked) {
              this
                  .widget
                  .dataService
                  .removeFromLiked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);

              WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                (_) => setState(
                  () {
                    _isLiked = false;
                    this.userIdsWhichLiked = this.widget.game.likes_user_ids;
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
            this
                .widget
                .dataService
                .addToDisliked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);
          }
          this.widget.dataService.makeSureLikedAboveZero();
          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
            (_) => setState(
              () {
                this._isDisliked = !this._isDisliked;
                this.userIdsWhichDisliked = this.widget.game.dislikes_user_ids;
              },
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

And displaying the text just looks like this:

```
 createDislikeText() {
    return Text(
      this.widget.game.dislikes_user_ids.length.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 11,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Do you guys have any idea why it sometimes works and sometimes it does not? In my DatabaseService I am awaiting every change tho.

Thank you guys!!

Edit for screenshots:
[image: Screenshot of UI]

And that's how the like button is implemented:

```
 createLikeButton() {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          child: Icon(
            this._isLiked ? Icons.thumb_up_alt : Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_isLiked) {
              this
                  .widget
                  .dataService
                  .removeFromLiked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);
            } else {
              if (_isDisliked) {
                this
                    .widget
                    .dataService
                    .removeFromDisliked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);

                WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                  (_) => setState(
                    () {
                      _isDisliked = !_isDisliked;
                      this.userIdsWhichDisliked =
                          this.widget.game.dislikes_user_ids;
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
              this.widget.dataService.addToLiked(this.widget.game.referenceId!);

              this.widget.dataService.makeSureLikedAboveZero();
              WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                (_) => setState(
                  () {
                    this._isLiked = !this._isLiked;
                    this.userIdsWhichLiked = this.widget.game.likes_user_ids;
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
          });
        });
  }
```

Comment: Pardon, but would you kindly provide some screenshots of the UI you're creating? I'm asking because I feel that some visual context would make it easier to debug. Lastly, would you kindly add the construction of the Like Button? You've included the Dislike button, but if they share values in the widget, it's possible they're stepping on eachother's toes

Comment: @fabc Thank you for answering! I editted the question, I Hope that provides some more information!

Comment: Pardon the delay in my message, but I can see a couple of things that I think are causing issues: `addToDisliked` and `addToLiked` are being called outside of the conditions of `_isLiked` and `_isDisliked`, which is good if the post is currently in neither but not if it's already in the lists then it might be added twice-over. Combine that with the fact that setState will call a build of the object and the object declares `_isLiked` and `_isDisliked` based on whether or not they're in the list, and you might get weird behaviour. Does this still happen with completely new objects?

Comment: @fabc i already tried everything at the moment, the issue that it is "stuck" only appears when I click on tabs on the bottom navigation and come back to this tab. It seems like the tab doesnt realise it is open. In the Database I can see the changes :( 
The Bottom Navigation is simply a Row with 5 GestureDetectors, on Tab it tells a controller to navigate to the selected page.

The code above also takes care of if someone is already in the list actually.